# google app engine cron.xml doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The `cron.xml` of GAE doesn't pick up the servlet specified in `<cron>` under `<cronentries>`. Also the cron configuration link is missing in the admin console. If anyone faced the same issue please let me know the solution. Btw. I am using GAE 1.4.3 with Eclipse plugin.

`cron.xml:`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <cronentries>
  <cron>
  <url>/schedulerServlet</url>
  <description>triggered every 2 minutes</description>
  <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
  </cronentries>
```

`servlet code:`

```
  public class SchedulerServlet extends HttpServlet {
     // doGet method definition{
        // things to do 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Add the cron.xml and a snippet of your servlet.

Comment: Is the servlet actually mapped to that URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you testing this on the local development environment? If so, I am afraid to [tell you](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html#Cron_Support_in_the_Development_Server) that it is not supported on local development server.

Once you upload your code to GAE, you will see that it works like a charm.

Comment: Yes Iam testing this on local dev environment

Comment: You can use the work around specified on the link I gave you, though.